# Why signal instead of broadcast works if we need to print the results of multiple thread calculations in specific order?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, condition-variable

In my code below, I create a pool of threads which do some computation on a common array. I want the computation to be done in parallel however, I want to print the results of the computation such that a thread id x doesn't print its results before thread id y, where x > y. So first I want to print the results of id 0, then 1, 2, etc.

I'm using pthreads to do this. Originally I used `pthread_cond_broadcast` to wake up blocked threads (everything worked) but then I tried `pthread_cond_signal` just out of curiosity. Interestingly enough, the program still works correctly.

But I don't understand why. That is:

1. I spawn, say 5 threads. All of them complete their calculations.
2. 4 of them get blocked, while thread id 0 prints its result and signals.
3. According to the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) `pthread_cond_signal` "shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked". So maybe it unblocks thread id 3.
4. thread id 3 cannot proceed because it's not its turn yet to print the result so it waits.
5. deadlock ensues.

So why does `pthread_cond_signal` still work? Is it because of repeated sheer luck or because my OS creates a queue of blocked threads and thread id 1 just happens to be in the head of this queue?

This is my code (the wait/signal logic is in function `ComputeThread`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEFAULT_VAL 5
#define ARR_LEN 5
#define THREADS_NUM 5

typedef struct helper_t {
    int * currId;
    int threadId;
    int * computeArr;
    pthread_mutex_t * mutex;
    pthread_cond_t * cond;
} helper_t;

int * initComputeArr(int len) {
    int i;
    int * computeArr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        computeArr[i] = DEFAULT_VAL;
    }
    return computeArr;
}

void mallocError() {
    printf("malloc error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

helper_t * initHelpers(pthread_mutex_t * mutex, pthread_cond_t * cond, int * computeArr) {
    int i;
    helper_t * helpers = (helper_t *) malloc(sizeof(helper_t) * THREADS_NUM);
    int * currId = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(!helpers || !currId) {
        mallocError();
    } else {
        *currId = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM; i++) {
            helpers[i].mutex = mutex;
            helpers[i].cond = cond;
            helpers[i].computeArr = computeArr;
            helpers[i].currId = currId;
            helpers[i].threadId = i;
        }
    }
    return helpers;
}

void printHelper(helper_t * h) {
    printf("threadId %d, currId %d\n", h->threadId, *h->currId);
}

void printHelpers(helper_t * h, int len) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printHelper(&h[i]);
    }
}

int calc(int * arr, int uptoIndex) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= uptoIndex; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

void * ComputeThread(void * arg) {
    int calcResult;
    helper_t * h = (helper_t *) arg;
    pthread_mutex_t * mutex = h->mutex;
    pthread_cond_t * cond = h->cond;
    calcResult = calc(h->computeArr, h->threadId);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    while(*h->currId != h->threadId) {
        printf("id %d waiting...\n", h->threadId);
        pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
    }
    printf("curr %d, threadId %d, result %d\n", *h->currId, h->threadId, calcResult);
    (*h->currId)++;
    pthread_cond_signal(cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    pthread_exit((void *) calcResult);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    int * computeArr;
    int * calcResutls;
    helper_t * helpers;
    pthread_t threads[THREADS_NUM];

    computeArr = initComputeArr(ARR_LEN);
    calcResutls = initComputeArr(ARR_LEN);
    helpers = initHelpers(&mutex, &cond, computeArr);
    printHelpers(helpers, THREADS_NUM);

    for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ComputeThread, (void *) &helpers[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < THREADS_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], (void **) &calcResutls[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", calcResutls[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("end of calc\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see undefined behaviour getting invoked as the code misses to initialise the mutex and the condition.

Comment: Testing the result a function-calls for error is debugging for free.

Comment: BTW, the relevant documentation to `pthread_cond_broadcast()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html).

Comment: @alk that was the problem! once I initialized mutex and cond variables indeed signal causes deadlock. I didn't understand what you meant regarding testing function calls result

Comment: Well, when mentioning to test function call for error I was naively imagining that the call getting passed the uninitialised mutex or condition would have errored out pointing you to this. But rereading the docs I was reminded that this probably weren't the case ...

Comment: Still, if a function could fail it will do so sooner or later. So it is good practise to test for these cases, at least if such failure would impact the programs functionality. If the code you show would steer a plane I wouldn't enter it ... ;-)

Comment: BTW^2: There is no need to cast from/to `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: @alk do you have some specific tip regarding testing these cases? I'm genuinely interested, but I'm not sure there's something specific that could've been done without knowing what to test for.

Comment: For example see the "*RETURN VALUE*" section in the documentation I linked. Same for all other `pthread_*()` functions. Also `malloc() ` can fail. It would return `NULL` in this case.

Comment: An implementation could have `pthread_cond_broadcast()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` do exactly the same thing (wake all blocked threads) and be perfectly compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see undefined behaviour getting invoked as the code misses to initialise the mutex and the condition.